# Is this character really an Avenger?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

I'm asking about

> the Scarlet Witch.

She (and another character) worked with Hydra before the Avengers took the sceptre. When they found out Ultron was planning to destroy the world, they decided to help the Avengers save it.

I can't help but think that if any Hydra agents had been there, they'd probably have tried to stop Ultron as well. This wouldn't make them "good", it would just be because they and the Avengers had a common enemy, as Hydra probably wouldn't want the world to be destroyed either. Even saving the citizens wouldn't mean they stopped being Hydra, it would just mean they're less "evil" than others. Their main goals could still be the same.

Yet Hawkeye clearly said he considered her an Avenger, and in the end she seems to be part of the team. Was she shown to have changed her mind about any of Hydra's goals?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I understood the movie, she was not really a Hydra agent: she is

> a citizen of Sokovia that decided to accept to participate to Hydra's experiments on human beings to fulfill her revenge on the Avengers. For reasons that are not totally clear to me (maybe something related to Captain America 2: the Winter Soldier or the TV show Agents of Shield), Hydra succeeded in turning Sokovia's population against the Avengers. We can witness this by the protests against Stark Industries shown at the beginning of the movie. In particular, the family of QuickSilver and the Scarlet Witch was killed during the explosion of a shell manufactured by Stark Industries. They then decided to join Hydra and to participate to their experiments.

She changes her allegiance when she sees that the Avengers are not only here to destroy the villain

> the villain that they created, under telepathic suggestion from Scarlet Witch

but also to protect Sokovia's population. So it is mostly the other way around: the Avengers aren't accepting a former enemy, but she understands that the Avengers can be trusted and are working for the protection of mankind.

*Bonus*: the Avengers already trust Natasha Romanov, a forger Russian assassin, and Bruce Banner, though not a bad guy can instantly transform into a unstoppable monster.

---

Edit: as said in the comments, it is not clear

> if the population is against all Avengers or only Tony Stark. It is said that Stark financially supports the Avengers after the collapse of SHIELD organization, and Stark Tower has been renamed Avengers Tower. It seems to me that Stark is the official "face" of the Avengers.

Comment: The population of Sokovia wasn't ever shown to be anti-Avengers, as far as I could tell; instead all of their hate seemed to be reserved solely for Tony Stark/Iron Man. The negative propaganda posters are of Iron Man, they attack his automated suits, and it was Stark Industries shells that were used to destroy the city in the attack that killed Scarlet Witch and Quicksilver's parents.

Comment: They may attack automated suits because they serves as a support force for the Avengers mission in Sokovia. All the other points are more than valid though. I'll edit my answer. My memory was not clear about the attack that killed QuickSilver and Scarlet Witch's parents.

Comment: They are against Stark alone. If you notice the backdrops in several scenes from Sokovia, you'll see Iron man graffiti on walls with skulls and crosses and so on.